# Setting up SSO shibolleth for school project

Tags: php, authentication, single-sign-on

Me and a team are setting up a website that is supposed to be used for attendance purposes at our college. Originally we used Lamp and created our own db and we handled all of our own logins. But now we have been tasked with moving to AWS instead but with a added requirement. They want my login page to use a sso through our school canvas. Now I have a general understanding of what it is and how it works but I can't find anything to help me set it up. Originally my login page communicates with the the db using php. But I'm lost on how to set up my login page to use sso to authenticate the user. The school uses shibboleth sso system for canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I would like suggest you to use emerSSL as SSO login system. I think, it would be brilliant solution for your school project. This page contains documentation and PHP code samples for Apache and Nginx web servers: https://emerssl.emercoin.com/

Answer (score 0):

As your school uses Shibboleth which acts as a SAML Identity Provider, you could use [mod_auth_mellon](https://github.com/UNINETT/mod_auth_mellon) for Apache http server or [SimpleSAMLPHP](https://simplesamlphp.org/) to act as a SAML Service Provider. [SAML](https://wiki.oasis-open.org/security/Saml2TechOverview) would then be used as the technology for web browser based Single Sign On.

Answer (score 0):

The SSO authentication process is conceptually similar to OAuth, if you are familiar with that technology.

Instead of communicating directly with your database, your login page will send users to a 3rd party (in this case, a Shibboleth instance).

That third party will authenticate the user, and send them back to your application. There will be a signed SAML response in the URL - you'll need to decode this string into an XML document that includes information about the user account.

You would then take this information, i.e. the user's email address, and use it to sign them into your application by creating a session.

Since you are building a single tenant application (where only users from this one school's Shibboleth IDP are going to be signing in) you have a bit easier time than if you needed to support multiple tenants.

With that general overview, I'd suggest checking out OneLogin's developer site and PHP toolkit - https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/php

That tutorial is primarily for OneLogin as the Identity Provider - you'll need to figure out how to accomplish the equivalent inside the school's Shibboleth instance in order to create the secure handshake between Shibboleth and your application.

I'm also the maintainer of an open source project which could be helpful in this regard, but is primarily geared towards multi-tenancy. I'm happy to help if this seems like it could work for you - https://github.com/enterprise-oss/osso